# Why there are "grid spaces" between my sprites when the coordinates looks good?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My sprites are 16x16, the PixelsPerUnit is 99 and the Grid sizes are 0.16.

[image]

I debug.loged the sprite coordinates, and they are next to each other like: (0,0),(0,1),(-1,1)....
I tried resizing the tile set, the grids, but nothing seems to work. It worked perfectly a couple of days ago.

Comment: Can you clarify what the image shows? (also note that SO is for coding questions, if this is not related to code in Unit3d it is possible that [gamedev.se] is better place - check they help on what is on-topic before moving there so)

Answer (score 1):

I found 99 a strange PPU to work with 16x16px sprites. What you are seein might be some kind of artifact derived from the fact that 16/99 returns a repeating decimal *(or periodic number as i know them)*, so its not exactly 0.16.

Wy not 16 PPU and GrizSize 1?

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but I don't know how! I have tried this too, but never mind that, thank you very much!

Comment: Pixels Per Unit is how many pixels will represent 1 unit in editor, so if you want to calculate the size of a 16x16 sprite in units you divide 16/99 and you get 0.1616161616161616161616161616... and that to infinity. Since your grid is set to 0.16 theres always a gap between.
If you set it to 16 its now 16/16 = 1 meanin your grid have exactly 16 pixels or 1 unit with no gap between.
You can go with other divisible numbers like 32, meaning that 1 unit will represent 2 sprites long (and 4 squared).